# Specflow filter via dotnet test CLI

Tags: .net, nunit, specflow

I'm using the `dotnet test` CLI with specflow and would like to filter the tests using feature name. I have no problem filtering on specflow tag values, but have not had luck filtering on feature name.

Specflow documentation explains that `testpath:Feature:MyFeatureName1` should work. However, I have not found the proper way have that work through the `dotnet test` command line.

This works for tags only:

`Category=MyTag1 & Category=MyTag2`

However, this does not work:

`Category=MyTag1 & Category=MyTag2 & Category=testpath:Feature:MyFeatureName1`

Is this possible?

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: Though I supposed with `dotnet test` it shouldn't matter, but the unit test provider is used to generate the feature.cs files. You can open those files to see if there are any annotations on the class or test methods that contain the feature title.

Comment: It's nunit. I'll check the feature.cs file tomorrow.

Comment: @GregBurghardt That did it! For feature names or scenario names, instead of "Category=tagname", use "Description=FeatureName" or "Description=ScenarioName". If you want the points, then spin up an answer and I'll accept. :-)

Comment: You can answer your own question. You figured it out. There is absolutely nothing wrong with posting your own answer and marking it. I've done that several times, myself. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I wouldn't have figured it out without your comment. Didn't want to rob you of the credit.